# changing the address port of Google App Engine - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

Is it possible to change the port address (8888) of Google App Engine ?
If yes, how do I to change the port address ?

**IDE :** Eclipse 4.3

Because I always got when I try to debug my webapp :

> Could not open the requested socket: Address already in use: bind

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stupid question but, Have you tried a different port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver). You can add the argument ( under Run configurations --> Arguments )

```
--port=1234
```

Now when the address is in use you have something either already running on that port, which usually is another instance of GAE, make sure to close all running instances from the eclipse console, then try again. Or just check whats using the default port by going there in a browser.

Answer (score 4):

**In case of Maven build you need to change the "pom.xml" file.**

(Ref.: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#specifying_a_port_for_local_testing)

find out the block like:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
     <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.15</version>
     <configuration>
         <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
         <port>8181</port>
         <address>0.0.0.0</address>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and if there is no `"<port...</port>"` tag try to add one like above and change the port no. (in my case i change it to 8181) as you desire.

Answer (score 4):

- Go to pom.xml file in your maven project.
- search for the tag < port > 
  ( normally in maven projects it comes as < port > 8080 < /port--> as a comment in the following piece of code or similar to that

```html
< plugin >
     < groupId >com.google.appengine< /groupId >
     < artifactId >appengine-maven-plugin< /artifactId >
     < version >1.9.4< /version >
     < configuration >
          < enableJarClasses >false< /enableJarClasses >
          < !-- address>0.0.0.0< /address >
          < port >8080< /port -- >
          < port >1234< /port > //**add your port here with < port > tags...**
     < /configuration >
< /plugin >
```

).

- save pom.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

If the port is unused intentionally and still if you are unable to claim that port then and abnormal termination of the service is causing the issue.
So to fix it.

You have to kill the process.

```
--->Go to command/terminal
--->type ps java (Shows the process for java)
---> then check the particular process to kill it or use (killall -9 java).
```

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, the easiest way to run the server on a different port is by creating a new App Engine Server instance. In the wizard you can select the port number you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running GWT devmode under a Web Application (if you are working with Eclipse and GWT Plugin) go to your configuration then "Arguments" (tab) > "Program Arguments" and add the port option

for example you must have something like this .....-codeServerPort 9997....
just add -port 8080 (if you want to use port 80 for example), then just run or debug as usual

The best configuration maybe is:

(For eclipse users) I don't know why but -port dissapear from the configuration, so then instead of changing port by for example -port 8080, you must instead set "-startupUrl 127.0.0.1:8080/MyWebApp";, notice I set here port 8080 so next time I run my config on Eclipse it will work fine without adding "-port" again and again. – Marce 1 min ago

Answer (score -1):

if this is the problem arose in running app inventor offline in browser then i think i have the solution, this could also help for other purpose. so just follow the steps below.(for windows user)
step 1:open cmd window and type "netstat -aon".
       you will see list of local address along with PID. for app inventor    offline 8888 is the local address, so i concern with 8888 port address and note the PID number .
step 2: now open task manager and click on detail tab. then locate the pid number that is noted for that port address and end the service associated with that pid number.now your port is free to use localhost:8888 to launch app inventor in offline.